# "Show user agent shadow DOM" equivalent in Firefox and IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

Chrome has the setting "Show user agent shadow DOM" that reveals the elements that make up inputs, etc. Is there an equivalent option for Firefox and Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems currently it's not supperted in FF and IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM And probably, this is why there's no option for it.